# WebSocket C++ Client and Server Lib

Tags: c++, websocket

Please suggest some very basic WebSocket Client/Serve libraries for C++.

I was using mongoose.c but I am getting very odd behaviours when setting the call back functions to instance functions (using a bit of pointer magic).

It does not need to have any SSL or anything, it's for a research prototype. 
I would like something that just can create a simple server and spin connections out. Then define some callback function or actively poll. For the client, simple send / receive.

If possible no `Boost`. I have no dependencies, so I would like something that comes as a header/cpp.

More info as per request on odd behaviour:

Websockets refuse all connections if `VS` project compiled in debug mode when using 'mongoose.c'. It has to do with compiling with the `/MTd` flag. Now, I can turn that flag off, but it breaks several other libraries. I have logged it with Cesanta, but I doubt they will get back to me any time soon.

I basically need websockets that can read and write streams. Sort of like a TCP socket library. I only send `JSON` objects across and there is no signing or handshaking.

I am going through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations to see if I can find anything useful.

Comment: https://github.com/Gregwar/mongoose-cpp

Comment: @strangeqargo: You do realise that you suggested based on the exact same library that I said I am using, right? mongoose-cpp is old and out of date

Comment: you didn't say anything about c++ wrapper, maybe you're using plain c ;-)

Comment: https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose latest commit 4 hours ago, by the way

Comment: @strangeqargo: I really don't want to sound pedantic. But, mongoose-ccp has nothing to do with mongoose.c by cesanta. With the former being based on one of the last mongoose.c released under MIT license, while the latter is by cesanta, which is now under a different license and it's in C.

Comment: I wanted to sell you mongoose in any way possible, but, alas. If you'll find some library, I hope you will share it with us.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but I suggest you to edit your question to prevent downvoting (show some work / search efforts done) They don't like library searchers here (

Comment: @strangeqargo: Yeah, it seems to be that way. To be honest, I am really at a lost. Even mongoose.c head has really changed direction. It's all for webservers and queuing requests. My case is a lot simpler, I just need the char* that comes in so I can parse it myself and reply. Don't want any handling.

Comment: may be you should show some example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? and go with moongoose (no, I'm not trying  to sell it another time) someone may help to cast<your_type> properly or something. Maybe your research project does not need websockets right away, maybe you can encapsulate your network code and later change  your network library to websockets or use some binary protocol with low latency if you need it (captain proto or protobuff)

Comment: Maybe describe the odd behavours and show the code that produces them.  Maybe we can figure out how to make it work.

Comment: @strangeqargo: Unfortunately, I cannot do without WS. It's got to do with the fact that we actively want to use web browsers as clients (use case).

Comment: https://github.com/katzarsky/WebSocket ? Did you try extensive search on github with c++ filter?

Comment: @strangeqargo: I haven't seen that one.I'll have a look. I am currently checking a few other ones, see if I can adapt them.

Comment: I'm writing a [library in C for server authoring](https://github.com/boazsegev/c-server-tools) (libraries, in plural, actually). Using the library it's [easy to write websocket services](https://github.com/boazsegev/c-server-tools#websocket---for-real-time-web-applications). I didn't write the TLS part just yet, as I'm having trouble with the available crypto libraries... Anyway, I know it's not C++, but I'd love it if you checked it out and provided any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at **Libuv** ? its written in C but its the network layer underneath Node.js so it works pretty well.

Here is some tutorial that I think worth mention:
[Building a multiplayer game server with Libuv](http://www.gamedevcraft.com/2016/08/part-1-multiplayer-websocket-game.html)